# Convergence of sequence in compact topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In my research, $X$ is a compact topological space. I need to find a sequence of open covers $\{\mathcal{U}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that if $\{x_n, y_n\}\prec \mathcal{U}_n$ and $x_n\to x$, then $y_n\to x$. Note that $\{x, y\}\prec\mathcal{U}$ means that $\{x, y\}\subseteq C$ for some $C\in\mathcal{U}$.

Can you help me to find it.

Comment: Is you space metrizable? I don't think  this is true in general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy,  $X$ is a compact topological space but it  is not metrizable. Can I use Finite Intersection Property of $X$?

Comment: Is $X$ first countable?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma,  What can say about a compact first countable space?

Comment: If $U_n(x)$ is a decreasing countable local base at $x$ for each $x$, maybe you could do things with $\mathcal{U}_n = \{U_n(x): x \in X\}$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, if $\{x_n, y_n\}\prec \mathcal{U}_n$ and $x_n\to x$, can I say that $y_n\to x$? ($X$ is compact and first countable)

Comment: Not possible in general. If $X=\beta\Bbb N\setminus\Bbb N,$ and $x_n=x\ne y_n$ and $\{x,y_n\}\subset C_n\in U_n,$ then $x\in int (\;\cap_{n\in \Bbb N} (C_n\setminus \{y_n\})\;) .$